# how to find $\ln(-e)$

Tags: logarithms

I don't really understand the step by step procedure on how to calculate this? That $-$ confuses me, because I don't understand how there can be an $\ln$ of a negative number. Can someone please explain? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have this question correct? You cannot take logarithms of negative numbers. Where did you find this question?

Comment: $\ln(-e)=\ln(-1)+1$. Now use $e^{i (2k+1)\pi} = -1$

Comment: $\ln$ is only defined for positive numbers.

Comment: That's correct, in the real numbers you can't take the logarithm of a negative number.  It's likely that what you think the question is asking is not what it's really asking.  Why don't you provide more context?

Comment: @ErickWong I don't have any more context, I have just been given this problem to solve. An online calculator gives me the answer $1 + i \pi$, but I am not sure how.

Comment: There isn't any real logarithm of a negative number.  And in the complex numbers the definition of a logarithm is derived in a different manner.  In a nutshell, a  complex number can be expressed as $e^{a+ib}=e^a (\cos b + i \sin b) $ in this case $e^{a+ib}=e^1 (-1+i0) $ so $a=1$ and $b=(2k+1)\pi $ and $\ln -e = 1+i (2k+1)\pi $ for any integer $k $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are referring to the complex logarithmic function which is defined as:

$\ln(z) = \ln(r) + i(\theta+2\pi k)$, where $z = re^{i\theta}, k\in \mathbb Z$.

Applying that here, since $-e = e\times e^{i\pi}$, then $\ln(-e) = \ln(e)+ i(\pi+ 2\pi k) = 1 + i(\pi+ 2\pi k)$.

Comment: You missed the $2n\pi$ factor. Check the comment section for @samjoe 's answer.

Comment: @Rajat thanks. Changed.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, from Euler's equation and more specifically Euler's identity you can define a logarithm of a negative number.

If you had $\ln (-1)$, all you would have to do is add it to $\ln (n)$ to get $\ln (-n)$. The axioms defined for logs remain the same.

Euler's equation: $e^{i\pi}=-1 \implies \ln({-1})=i\pi$

I know there's a periodicity of $2\pi$ that I haven't accounted for yet but I think that's a fair enough point made.

I assume you're not that familiar with complex numbers so like any good fellow, I wish you good tidings on the yellow brick road you will trod in complex numbers.

What they are: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLiaHhY2iBX9g6KIvZ_703G3KJXapKkNaF

Why $e$ shows up: https://youtu.be/mvmuCPvRoWQ